# PHP - Best way to print multiplication table

Tags: php, list, loops, multiplication

Basic PHP. I decided to print a list of 10 multiples of 17.5, like:

17.5 | 35 | 52.5 | 70 | 87.5 | 105 | 122.5 | 140 | 157.5 | 175 |

So I first used this loop:

```
<?php
$number = 17.5;
$result = 0;
$i = 0;
while ($i < 10) {
  $result += $number;
  echo $result.' | ';
  $i++;  }
```

Well, it works. Then I switched to this, that is quite shorter:

```
$i = 1;
$result = 17.5;
while ($i <= 10) {
  echo $result * $i.' | ';
  $i++;  }
```

But I'm sure there is a better way. What's the best syntax?

Comment: The best syntax is the one that's easiest to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$results = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++){
    $results[] = $i * 17.5;
}
echo implode(' | ', $results);
```

Or better

```
echo implode(' | ', range(17.5, 17.5*10, 17.5));
```

Comment: I like how this doesn't add a pipe at the end

Answer (score 3):

There are many quicker ways to achieve this. Take this simple `for` loop for example:

```
$num = '17.5';

for($i = 1; $i <=10; $i++) {
    $array[] = $i * $num; 
}
echo implode(' | ', $array);
```

[**Example**](http://www.tehplayground.com/#MSTNJy0uP)

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = 17.5;
for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++){
    echo  ($i * $result) .' | ';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I like mine best:

```
$s = $t = '17.5';
while($s < $t*10){
    echo ($s += $t).' | ';
}
```

Comment: wow, I like this logic